# BufferedReader isn't reading whole string

Tags: java

I'm playing around with sockets, but seem to have an issue with the Buffered-Reader not reading the whole string after I enter a space (e.g. "hi there", it will only print "hi") has anyone else had this issue before?

```
    Server e = new Server();

    e.start();
    ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(41021);
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
    System.out.println("Server: (Network.Client) connected");
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream());


    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);




        System.out.println("Client: " + bufferedReader.readLine());


        serverSocket.close();
        socket.close();



}


@Override

public void run() {


    try {


        Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 41021);
        while (socket.isConnected()) {
            PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());


            printWriter.println(new Scanner(System.in).next());
            printWriter.flush();


        }


        socket.close();


    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Why are you using that strange loop? You should create a `Scanner` on `System.in` only once. You can loop the input with something like `while(s.hasNextLine() && !message.equals("exit"))` but nothing else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this happens because in line
`printWriter.println(new Scanner(System.in).next());`
you using `next();` instead of `nextLine();`
Try `nextLine();` and notice me if it is working.